# Paypal unsuccess Transaction takes to Success URL

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment

I am using HTML5 and CSS3 to design website with Paypal Implementation. I have Implemented Paypal Donation Button as follows:

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
        <input type="hidden" id ="businessAccount" name="business" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
        <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add Some Words about this Donation:">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Donate">
        <input id="amount" type="hidden" name="amount" value="" >
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        <input id="notify_url" type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="">
        <input id="return" type="hidden" name="return" value="">
        <input id="cancel_return" type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="">
        <input id="custom" type="hidden" name="custom" value="">


 </form>
```

I am setting their values Using jQuery as :

```
  $("#return").val(PAYPAL_SUCCESS_URL);
  $("#notify_url").val(PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL);
  $("#cancel_return").val(PAYPAL_CANCEL_RETURN_URL);
```

i have Put wrong Merchant's Paypal AccountId  (test@Yahoo.com). When click on checkout it leads user to Payment Error Page as shown in Picture below
[image]

On this page , when user click on `Return to Merchant's` , The Success URL is opening. I am confused here if there is no payment transaction , then instead of calling `cancel_return` why it is calling `return` URL ???

Comment: Where have you defined PAYPAL_SUCCESS_URL? Maybe you put in there the wrong URL

Comment: PAYPAL_SUCCESS_URL is setting fine , because i have tested it when the transaction is completed successfully , it is opening PAYPAL_SUCCESS_URL.

Comment: GUess you are mixxing up something somewhere

Comment: when transaction successfully completed , it is opening PAYPAL_SUCCESS_URL , when with correct Merchant's Paypal ID and Unsuccessful transaction , Then it is opening PAYPAL_CANCEL_RETURN_URL , But when i put the invalid Merchant's Paypal ID, It is opening  PAYPAL_SUCCESS_URL .. This Is what confusing me

Comment: actually i am getting this ID from database , and i was testing it with dummy account when i face that problem , i then change multiple dummy ID , it showed me same and redirect to Success Page